# How to check what type of node or class/id is the parent element in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How can I check if the closest parent element is type of node, i.e. `<li>, <div>, <p>, etc`, or is a class name, in jquery?

I made the code below, but it doesn't work:

```
var msgSpan = $('<span/>', {class: 'msg'});

function checkField(field) {
    if (field.closest('li')) {
        console.log('Parent is an Li');
        field.closest('li').addClass('error').find('.input').before(msgSpan);
    } else if (field.closest('.parent')) {
        console.log('Parent is a class called .parent');
        field.closest('.parent').addClass('error').find('.input').before(msgSpan);
    }
}

// Usage
checkField($('input[type="text"]');
```

HTML:

```
<form id="search-jobs">
    <fieldset class="parent">
        <label for="jobs_search">Search jobs</label>
        <div class="input left">
            <input type="text" id="jobs_search" name="jobs_search" class="required" placeholder="Search jobs" />
        </div>
        <div class="btn-cont left">
            <input type="submit" id="" name="" class="button" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: `tagName` , `hasClass`  ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery -- you need `field.closest('li').length` and `field.closest('.parent').length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to achieve this without type checking the tags.

```
var msgSpan = "<div>Error</div>";
function checkField(field) {
    var $parent = (field.parents(".parent").length) ? field.parents(".parent"): field.parents("li");
    if($parent.length){
        $parent.addClass('error').find('input').before(msgSpan);
    }
}

checkField($("#jobs_search"));
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/kg3Nq/2/

Comment: This is the only correct answer. The other answers look for the immediate parent only, when it's obvious from the example HTML that the OP wants to traverse all ancestors, even if the terminology is a bit off.

Comment: @Juhan Just to improve my knowledge could you explain how my terminology is off?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the OP's terminology is off, not yours (he uses "parent" when he means "ancestor").

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the **immediate parent** element, you could use the following:

```
$parent = field.parent();
if ($parent.is('li, div, p, .className')) {
    $parent.addClass('error').find('.input').before(msgSpan);
}
```

Or, if you want to check the **closest** element:

```
$closest = field.closest('li, div, p, .className');
if ($closest.length) {
    // $closest[0].tagName (would give you the element type)
    // $closest[0].className (would give you the class, if one exists)
    $closest.addClass('error').find('.input').before(msgSpan);        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is) method

```
var msgSpan = $('<span/>', {class: 'msg'});

function checkField(field) {
    var parent = field.parent();

    if (parent.is('li')) {
        console.log('Parent is an Li');
        parent.addClass('error').find('.input').before(msgSpan);
    } else if (parent.is('.parent')) {
        console.log('Parent is a class called .parent');
        parent.addClass('error').find('.input').before(msgSpan);
    }
}

// Usage
checkField( $('input[type="text"]') );
```

Keep in mind though that since you are passing as field a selection the might match multiple `input` elements, the code will only work with the first one found.. (*in other words you should use a more specific selector that only matches one element*)

Something like

```
checkField( $('input[type="text"]').first() );
```

---

Additionally, you seem to be running the same code for both cases (*except the log message*). If that is the intended behavior you could use a single check

```
function checkField(field) {
    var parent = field.parent();

    if (parent.is('li') || parent.is('.parent')) {
        parent.addClass('error').find('.input').before(msgSpan);
    }
}
```